# Unable to drag and drop using robot framework. UI is built with angular cdk. The application is based on electron app

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, robotframework-pythonremoteserver

I am facing an issue in drag and drop using robot framework. I am automating drag and drop with a desktop application which is built on electron open source framework.
The UI contains Available section and Output section which is implemented as Component Dev Kit (CDK) component.
Can anyone please help in this issue.
My Test case gets passed but there is no actual drag and drop happens.

Thank you!!

I have tried a lot of possible ways which are not working.
Robot framework's Actionchains class is also not working, not even mouse movement occurred.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML and your code trials.

Comment: Did you enable remote-debugging-port in Electron app?